# Erro em Java - Cálculo da raiz quadrada

Tags: java, swing

Estava fazendo alguns exercícios básicos em Java e um deles pedia:

> Neste exemplo, utilizaremos o método `sqrt` da classe `Math` para extrair a raiz quadrada do número que for digitado em uma caixa de texto, um componente 'Campo de texto' para o usuário digitar o número desejado, e um componente 'Rótulo' para exibir o resultado, ou seja, a raiz quadrada desse número.

Aí eu fiz tudo direito, só que deu um problema, quando eu digito a 1 letra:

> ```
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
>     at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
>     at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
>     at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
>     at Apresentacao.TelaRaiz.jtNumeroKeyPressed(TelaRaiz.java:67)
>     at Apresentacao.TelaRaiz.access$000(TelaRaiz.java:12)
>     at Apresentacao.TelaRaiz$1.keyPressed(TelaRaiz.java:38)
>     at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6491)
>     at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2832)
>     at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6310)
>     at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>     at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954)
>     at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:806)
>     at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1074)
>     at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:945)
>     at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:771)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4760)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
>     at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
> ```

Ele executa tudo e mesmo com erro ele calcula a raiz, mas somente quando eu digito a segunda letra, ou quando eu digito a primeira letra e aperto ENTER. Porque está dando esse erro? Eu queria que quando digitasse, ele capturasse e mostrasse o resultado.

Trecho de Erro:

```java
private void jtNumeroKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                    
        int i = (int)(Double.parseDouble(jtNumero.getText()));
        jlResultado.setText("A raiz quadrada de: "+ i + " é: " + Math.sqrt(i));
    }
```

Comment: Coloque o trecho do seu código onde ocorre o erro para podermos entender melhor.

Answer (score 3):

O erro ocorre porque está sendo passada uma String vazia para o método parse. Tente validar antes de capturar o valor do campo:

```
private void jtNumeroKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt){
    String valor = jtNumero.getText().trim();

    if(valor.isEmpty()){
        //exibe algo se o campo estiver vazio
    } else {
        int i = (int)(Double.parseDouble(valor));
        jlResultado.setText("A raiz quadrada de: "+ i + " é: " + Math.sqrt(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Tem como você me ajudar, eu quero que quando eu digite já apareça o resultado tbm, sem precisar ter que apertar outra tecla

Comment: @user41657988463 não entendi, se o valor for passado em branco, não tem porque faze parse, vai dar erro, como você já percebeu na pergunta.

Comment: É que tá dando erro, mas eu digito um valor

Comment: @user41657988463 continuo nao entendendo.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que vc está usando o evento `KeyPressed`. Este evento captura a tecla pressionada, mas neste momento o atributo text do componente ainda está com o valor antigo.
Use o evento `KeyReleased`, pois ele é acionado após a tecla ser solta e o text já está com o conteúdo definitivo.

```
private void jtNumeroKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                        
    if ("".equals(jtNumero.getText())){return;}
    int i = (int)(Double.parseDouble(jtNumero.getText()));
    jlResultado.setText("A raiz quadrada de: "+ i + " é: " + Math.sqrt(i));
}
```

Comment: se for um numero de dois digitos, acho que vai ocorrer a mesma coisa.

Comment: Negativo! Pois veja que estou pegando o atributo text, que a esta altura já estará atualizado.

Comment: Só daria este problema que vc mencionou se eu capturasse a tecla pelo parametro `evt`.

Answer (score 1):

Tente fazer assim:

```
private void jtNumeroKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    try {                     
        double i = Double.parseDouble(jtNumero.getText());
        jlResultado.setText("A raiz quadrada de " + i + " é " + Math.sqrt(i) + ".");
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        jlResultado.setText("Por favor, digite um número válido.");
    }
}
```

Aqui, o `catch` está capturando a exceção caso o valor digitado não seja numérico. Além disso, o valor digitado deve ser um `double`, e não um `int`. Desta forma, a raiz quadrada de `1.21` será `1.1`, e não `1`.